# JUnit Extensions randombeans - exclude property of object within collection

Tags: unit-testing, junit, junit5, random-beans

I'm using [junit-extensions/randomBeans](https://glytching.github.io/junit-extensions/randomBeans) and I use something like this:

```
@Random(type = Album.class, excludes = {"images.id", "images.lastUpdate"})
private List<Album> albums;
```

Album contains `List<Image> images` and I'm trying to exclude `Image.id` and `Image.lastUpdate` from random generation but it doesn't work.

I also tried with `excludes = {"images[].id", "images[].lastUpdate"}` but it also doesn't work.

Any idea about how to exclude Image's `id` and `lastUpdate` from random generation?

**EDIT**

With the below:

```
@Random(excludes = {"id", "dirty", "cover", "lastUpdate", "images.id",
            "images.lastUpdate", "images.status", "images.deleted"})
private Album specialAlbum;
```

the 1th image (index 0) always "happens" to be correctly generated but the others have excluded properties set.

Also I'm using:

```
public class RandomBeansExtensionEx extends RandomBeansExtension
        implements IEnhancedRandom {
    public RandomBeansExtensionEx() throws IllegalAccessException {
        super();
        FieldUtils.writeField(this, "random",
                EnhancedRandomBuilder.aNewEnhancedRandomBuilder()
        .objectPoolSize(100)
        .overrideDefaultInitialization(true)
        .charset(forName("UTF-8"))
        .randomize(Integer.class, (Supplier<Integer>) () ->
                ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE))
        .randomize(Long.class, (Supplier<Long>) () ->
                ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(0, Long.MAX_VALUE))
        .stringLengthRange(3, 15)
        .collectionSizeRange(1, 50)
        .scanClasspathForConcreteTypes(true)
        .build(), true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUnit Extensions contains [a test case](https://github.com/glytching/junit-extensions/blob/293c37b7bacc7657e4bb0649aa614fc4594317e9/src/test/java/io/github/glytching/junit/extension/random/RandomBeansExtensionParameterTest.java#L107) which verifies exclusion for nested attributes:

```
  @Test
  public void canInjectRandomPartiallyPopulatedDomainObjects(
      @Random(size = 2, type = DomainObject.class, excludes = {"wotsits", "id", "nestedDomainObject.address"})
          List<DomainObject> anyPartiallyPopulatedDomainObjects) {
    assertThat(anyPartiallyPopulatedDomainObjects, notNullValue());
    assertThat(anyPartiallyPopulatedDomainObjects.size(), is(2));
    anyPartiallyPopulatedDomainObjects.forEach(AssertionUtil::assertThatDomainObjectIsPartiallyPopulated);
  }
```

In this test case, the RandomBeans extension provides a `List<DomainObject>` with two instances of `DomainObject` each of which has the following features:

- the `wotsits` collection is excluded i.e. is `null`
- the `id` attribute is excluded i.e. is `0L` since this is the default value for a `long`
- the `address` attribute of each `nestedDomainObject` is `null`

This shows that excluding attributes of nested objects is a matter of using dot notation (`nestedDomainObject.address`.

**Update**: using the code from your [GitHub repo](https://github.com/adrhc/photos-server) I have created the following minimal reproduction case:

```
@ExtendWith(RandomBeansExtensionEx.class)
public class NestedAttributeTest {

    @Random(excludes = {"id", "dirty", "cover", "lastUpdate", "images.id", "images.lastUpdate", "images.status", "images.deleted"})
    private Album specialAlbum;

    @Test
    void testAttributeExclusion() {
        assertThat(specialAlbum.getId(), nullValue());
        assertThat(specialAlbum.getCover(), nullValue());
        assertThat(specialAlbum.getLastUpdate(), nullValue());
        assertThat(specialAlbum.getImages(), notNullValue());
        for (Image image : specialAlbum.getImages()) {
            assertThat(image.getId(), nullValue());
            assertThat(image.getLastUpdate(), nullValue());
        }
    }
}
```

This test case fails, thereby reproducing your issue.

With this reproduction case I can see that the issue affecting you is caused by the bi-directional relationship between `Album` and `Image`. The fact that each `Image` contains a reference to its parent `Album` is causing RandomBeans' `RandomizationContext.getFieldFullName()` to derive an incorrect name for each attribute in `Image`.

1. On the first iteration it determines that the `id` field in the injected Image is named `image.id` and therefore it successfully excludes it.
2. On the second iteration it determines that the `id` field in the injected Image is named `images.album.images.id` and therefore it does not exclude it since that name is not in the 'excludes list'
3. On the third iteration it determines that the `id` field in the injected Image is named `images.album.images.album.images.id` and therefore it does not exclude it since that name is not in the 'excludes list'
   etc

You can verify this by ...

- Commenting `Image.album` and re running the minimal test I provided and you'll see that it passes.
- Changing the configuration to `.collectionSizeRange(1, 1)` such that each random collection has just one element and you'll see that the minimal test I provided passes.

As things stand RandomBeans (and hence RandomBeansExtension) does not support excluding nested attributes in the following scenario:

- The nested atributes are in a collection with more than 1 element
- The objects in that collection contain a back reference to the containing class
- The back reference attribute is not excluded

I think the fix here is to exclude the `item.album` attribute. The following test passes:

```
@ExtendWith(RandomBeansExtensionEx.class)
public class NestedAttributeTest {

    @Random(excludes = {"id", "dirty", "cover", "lastUpdate", "images.album", "images.id", "images.lastUpdate", "images.status", "images.deleted"})
    private Album specialAlbum;

    @Test
    void testAttributeExclusion() {
        assertThat(specialAlbum.getId(), nullValue());
        assertThat(specialAlbum.getCover(), nullValue());
        assertThat(specialAlbum.getLastUpdate(), nullValue());
        assertThat(specialAlbum.getImages(), notNullValue());
        for (Image image : specialAlbum.getImages()) {
            assertThat(image.getId(), nullValue());
            assertThat(image.getLastUpdate(), nullValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Re your latest updates to the question; I still cannot reproduce your issue. If you could provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), one which includes the minimal code to reproduce the issue then I'm sure I'll be able to diagnose. Can you reduce the issue to a simple pair of classes (`Album` and `Image`) and a small test case and update your question with those details? Given that the default behaviour of the RandomBeans extension is proven for the exclusion of nested attributes (by the test case I linked in my answer) I won't be able to diagnose your issue without a MCVE.

Comment: Use https://github.com/adrhc/photos-server.git. Use the appropriate @Random on `private Album specialAlbum`. Put a debug breakpoint for the first line in AlbumPageServiceTest.setUpSpecialAlbum and start debugging any test method. Check this.specialAlbum value when reaching the breakpoint. In order for the full test to work you'll also have to use _mysql_ and _exifweb-no-data.sql_ script but for our purpose it's enough the debugging.

Comment: I just ran that test and pausing on the first line of `AlbumPageServiceTest.setUpSpecialAlbum` I see that `specialAlbum` has been populated excluding `id, dirty, images, cover, lastUpdate` just like the annotation on that class member state. It's still not clear to me what you expect me to see.  Note: I commented out `@Junit5PhotosStagingDbConfig` because I don't have time to install mysql and run exifweb-no-data.sql ... I think that test case is missing out on the `M` in MCVE ... _"Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem"_ :)

Comment: I'll have another look if you can produce a minimal example (4 classes should suffice - Album, Image, RandomBeansExtensionEx and a small test case) which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Clearly missing the `M` part :D.  Please use `@Random(excludes = {"id", "dirty", "cover", "lastUpdate", "images.id", "images.lastUpdate", "images.status", "images.deleted"})` (the 1th commented line above `private Album specialAlbum`) and comment the currently used `@Random(excludes = {"id", "lastUpdate", "status", "deleted"})`.

Comment: Indeed I never intended to randomly generate the value of _item.album_ so there was my mistake. Thanks for pointing it to me.

Comment: Well, from my point of view is not a randombeans issue but only my misuse of it which now was clarified so I consider the thread SOLVED.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to mark this thread as solved but I missed that feature.